# Any ideas on how to find the limit of $L=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{7+x^2}-\sqrt{3+x^2}}{x-1}$

Tags: limits

Any ideas on how to find the limit of $$L=\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{7+x^2}-\sqrt{3+x^2}}{x-1}$$

We can proceed as follows $$L=\dfrac{\left(\sqrt[3]{7+x^2}-\sqrt{3+x^2}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{(7+x^2)^2}+\sqrt[3]{7+x^2}\sqrt{3+x^2}+3+x^2\right)}{(x-1)\ldots}\\=\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{7+x^2-(3+x^2)\sqrt{3+x^2}}{(x-1)\ldots}=\dfrac{(7+x^2)^2-(3+x^2)^3}{(x-1)\dots\left(7+x^2+(3+x^2)\sqrt{3+x^2}\right)}\\=\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{-x^5-x^4-9x^3-9x^2-22x-22}{\ldots\left(7+x^2+(3+x^2)\sqrt{3+x^2}\right)}=\dfrac{-20-44}{(7+1+4\cdot2)(4+2\cdot2+3+1)}=-\dfrac{64}{16\cdot12}=-\dfrac{1}{3}$$

The found solution works, but it is technically unpleasant. There is no insight, we just apply formulas sequentially. However, I think the problem can be solved in a more elegant and clever way.

Comment: What's wrong with using L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Indeed, using L'hopital's rule, $L=\lim\limits_{x\to1}\left[\frac13(7+x^2)^{-2/3}2x-\frac12(3+x^2)^{-1/2}2x\right]$ $=\frac13\frac142-\frac12\frac122=\frac16-\frac12=-\frac13$

Answer (score 1):

I'd substitute $y = x - 1$ and find the limit as $y\to 0$. Indeed,
$$\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{7+x^2}-\sqrt{3+x^2}}{x-1} = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{7 + (y+1)^2} - \sqrt{3 + (y+1)^2}}{y}.$$
Now, using L'Hopital's Rule,
$$\begin{align*}\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{7 + (y+1)^2} - \sqrt{3 + (y+1)^2}}{y} &= \lim_{y\to 0} \left(\frac13 (7 + (y+1)^2)^{-2/3} (2y+2) - \frac12 (3 + (y+1)^2)^{-1/2} (2y+2)\right)\\ &= \frac13 \cdot 8^{-2/3} \cdot 2 - \frac12 \cdot 4^{-1/2} \cdot 2\\ &= \frac16 - \frac12 = \frac{-1}3.\end{align*}$$

Comment: This is really just using the definition of the derivative, rather than L’Hôpital’s rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in more elegant way i.e using shorthand notation like $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n$, but any solution without L'Hopital's rule will be this ugly

Since $x^{n+1}- y^{n+1}=(x-y)\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n( x^k \cdot y^{n-k})\right) $, then
$$(x^2+7 )^{\frac 1 3}-(x^2+3)^{\frac{1}{2}}=  ((x^2+7)^2 )^{\frac 1 6}-((x^2+3)^3)^{\frac{1}{6}}$$
$$= \frac{(x^2+7)^2 - (x^2+3)^3}{\sum_\limits{k=0}^5 ((x^2+7)^2 )^{\frac k 6}\cdot ((x^2+3)^3)^{\frac{5-k}{6}}}$$

Since $(x^2+7)^2 - (x^2+3)^3= -(x-1)(x+1)(x^4+9x^2+22)$

Then $$ \lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{7+x^2}-\sqrt{3+x^2}}{x-1}= \lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{-(x-1)(x+1)(x^4+9x^2+22)}{(x-1)\sum_\limits{k=0}^5 ((x^2+7)^2 )^{\frac k 6}\cdot ((x^2+3)^3)^{\frac{5-k}{6}}}$$
$$=-\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{(x+1)(x^4+9x^2+22)}{\sum_\limits{k=0}^5 ((x^2+7)^2 )^{\frac k 6}\cdot ((x^2+3)^3)^{\frac{5-k}{6}}}= -\frac{2\cdot 32}{6 \times 32}$$

$$=\frac{-1}{3} \ \ \  \text{Q.E.D}$$